# hyper-v guest machines ping responses are very slow

Tags: performance, virtual-machine, response, ping, hyper-v

Just bought a new server, installed hyper-v and have two guest machines running windows 2012 R2.

When I ping the host machine or any other physical machines on my network, the ping responses are usually very fast <1ms, however, when I ping the guest machines the ping responses are much slower time=88, time=122, or much higher and inconsistent.

Could someone advise me if this is normal or what needs to be fixed?

thanks,
ik

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking if you have VMQ enabled. There are many articles on the web stating that sometimes if that is enabled your ping times are much slower. Try disabling VMQ in both the host network driver and the virtual adapters and see if that helps.

Here is one such article:
http://www.flexecom.com/high-ping-latency-in-hyper-v-virtual-machines/

Comment: I confirm. Dell server with Broadcom adapter. Switching "Virtual Machine Queues" to off on interface for VSwitch helps me.